# Geometery Nodes N Ripple Flow

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, geometry

Can someone point me in the right direction of going about creating a ripple effect that can be applied to a mesh that allows the object to be stationary and still project a ripple in a desired direction.It can be through geonodes or through another means.

Please see image [image]

Comment: Dynamic Paint provides something like this out of the box.. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/dynamic_paint/brush.html#waves .. is that heading in the right direction?

Comment: thankyou for your response. I am sure its part of the solution. I will start pursuing that avenue. I also have found this. https://nuggetblends.gumroad.com/l/wkbbqa?layout=profile&recommended_by=library  though i cant get the ripple to flow in a single directin